# Proving the limit of an alternating sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

Prove that $S_n$ converges to $0$ as $n\rightarrow$ $\infty$, where

$$
S_n = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 2/n & \text{ if $n$ is odd} \\ n/(n^2-1) & \text{ if $n$ is even }\end{array}\right.
$$

I want to check my proof as I feel that I am leaving something out.

Proof:

Fix $\epsilon >0$. Since $\frac{2}{n} \rightarrow 0$, $\exists N_1$ such that $|\frac{2}{n} -0|=\frac{2}{n}<\epsilon$. Likewise, since $\frac{n}{n^2-1} \rightarrow 0$, $\exists N_2$ such that $|\frac{n}{n^2-1}-0|=\frac{n}{n^2-1} < \frac{1}{n-3} <\epsilon,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ (since $3n-1 > 0, \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$).

Now choose $N_1 =\frac{2}{\epsilon}$, and $N_2 = \frac{1+3\epsilon}{\epsilon}$. Let $M = max\{N_1,N_2\}$, then $\forall n>M$:

If n is odd, then $|S_n - 0| = |\frac{2}{n} -0|=\frac{2}{n} < \frac{2}{M}<\epsilon$. If n is even, then $|S_n - 0| = |\frac{n}{n^2-1}-0|=\frac{n}{n^2-1} < \frac{1}{n-3} < \frac{1}{M-3} <\epsilon$. In both cases, $|S_n - 0|<\epsilon$. Done.

Is the proof complete? My concern is with choosing $M$ to be max. Usually, with simple sequences I can choose $N$ to be a single value (e.g. $2/\epsilon$)and plug it in $2/N$ to get $\epsilon$ but it seems weird to have the max of two numbers and the result is $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$
\frac{n}
{{n^2  - 1}} \leqslant \frac{n}
{{n^2  - \frac{{n^2 }}
{2}}} = \frac{n}
{{\frac{{n^2 }}
{2}}} = \frac{2}
{n}
$$
you have that for every $n \geq 2$ it is $S_n \leq \frac{2}{n}$. Therefore  it is enough to prove that 
$$
\forall \varepsilon  > 0\,\,\,\exists n\left( \varepsilon  \right) \in \mathbb{N}:\,\,\,\,n > n\left( \varepsilon  \right) \Rightarrow \left| {\frac{2}
{n}} \right| < \varepsilon 
$$
in order to obtain that 
$$
\forall \varepsilon  > 0\,\,\,\exists n\left( \varepsilon  \right) \in \mathbb{N}:\,\,\,\,n > n\left( \varepsilon  \right) \Rightarrow \left| {S_n } \right| < \varepsilon 
$$
If 
$$
\left| {\frac{2}
{n}} \right| < \varepsilon 
$$
you get that $n> \frac{2}{\varepsilon}=n(\varepsilon)$.

Comment: Don't you have to account for the case when n = 1?

Comment: Yes but this don't change the limit. Better, if you have a sequence and you don't consider any finite number of terms then its behavior as $
n \to  + \infty 
$
does not change. Therefore it is not important if my inequality start with $n=2$. This is in the heart of the limit's definition. You don't care what happens at the beginning of your sequence.  You care about it's definitive behavior. Hope to shed light about your doubt.

Comment: The definition of limit, roughly speaking, said " if n is large enough..." this means that you do not care about $S_1$ or $S_2$ or $S_m$ provided that m is fixed.

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is correct, more generally $(u_n)$ converges if and and only if $(u_{2n})$ and $(u_{2n+1})$ converge toward the same limit.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

I think the following will better help.$$0\le S_{n+1}\le {2\over n}$$